# What is the utility of inductors in circuits?

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism

I was wondering what all the possible purposes of inductors in electrical circuits are.

Inductors, as I understand, are wires wrapped in a helical pattern around some sort of solid material or simply air. I understand that they are able to create strong magnetic fields inside of and around them, and that they resist any changes in current.

I understand that one of the uses of inductors is to create motion, through the magnetic field they create, by pushing other magnets through or around them.

What other uses do they have in circuitry? Specifically, what would be uses for inductors that do not take advantage of the magnetic field they generate?

Comment: There is no use of an inductor that doesn't involve its magnetic field. The field stores energy, just like the electric field of a capacitor stores energy.

Comment: @Dave, And what about a bifilar coil?

Comment: I do not agree with closing the question. It is well worded as being limited to the two major areas of coil applications addressed in the @floppydisk answer.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist The entire point of a bifilar winding is to *reduce* inductance. I don't think it counts as an inductor if it's bifilar wound.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist this question is far to broad, and shows little to no research effort. Any answer which attempts to address it would be little more than regurgitating the 'Applications' section of the [Wikipedia entry for `Inductor'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor).

Comment: @Hearth, Agreed... I meant that the bifilar coil is an example of the OP's "inductors that do not take advantage of the magnetic field they generate"... but of course, it is not an inductor. By the way, for me bifilar coil and twisted pair are very good examples of the Don Lancaster's "elegant simplicity".

Answer (score 1):

As you said, inductors "resist any changes in current". So one use for them is to filter "noisy" power, where they allow steady current to pass through but filter out current spikes. Another example is in DC-DC converters where an inductor is "charged" with current and as the circuit is then opened and the current has nowhere to go, it is still being "pushed" by the inductor which creates a voltage spike, potentially higher than the input voltage. Same principle is used in gas cars to create a several kV spark from 12V battery voltage using inductor coils.